# How to avoid url with fastcgi_cache?

Tags: caching, nginx

How to avoid url with fastcgi_cache?
no need cache list e.g

```
projectdomain.com/a
projectdomain.com/b
projectdomain.com/c/d
```

vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http {
  fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/fastcgi/projectdomain.com levels=1:2 keys_zone=projectdomain.com:10m inactive=5m;
  add_header X-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

  ...
```

vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name projectdomain.com www.projectdomain.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/projectdomain.com.access.log;
  root /var/www/html/projectdomain.com;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  client_max_body_size 1G;

  location ~ ^/sitemap/(.*)$ {
    root /var/www/html/projectdomain.com/app/Sitemap/SitemapGz;
  }
  location /robots.txt {
    alias /var/www/html/projectdomain.com/app/robots.txt;
  }
  location ~ ^/(android-chrome-36x36.png|android-chrome-48x48.png|android-chrome-72x72.png|android-chrome-96x96.png|android-chrome-144x144.png|android-chrome-192x192.png|apple-touch-icon-57x57.png|apple-touch-icon-60x60.png|apple-touch-icon-72x72.png|apple-touch-icon-76x76.png|apple-touch-icon-114x114.png|apple-touch-icon-120x120.png|apple-touch-icon-144x144.png|apple-touch-icon-152x152.png|apple-touch-icon-180x180.png|apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png|apple-touch-icon.png|browserconfig.xml|favicon-16x16.png|favicon-32x32.png|favicon-96x96.png|favicon.ico|manifest.json|mstile-70x70.png|mstile-144x144.png|mstile-150x150.png|mstile-310x150.png|mstile-310x310.png|safari-pinned-tab.svg) {
    root /var/www/html/projectdomain.com/app/favicons;
  }
  location ~ ^/(images/|javascripts/|stylesheets/|fonts) {
    root /var/www/html/projectdomain.com/app/assets;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 32k;

    # cache
    fastcgi_cache projectdomain.com;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
    fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
    fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx provides two directives ([fastcgi_cache_bypass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache_bypass) and [fastcgi_no_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_no_cache)) for this task. The first one commands Nginx to ignore the already cached results if the given parameter is not an empty string or 0. The second one tells the server not to cache anything if the given parameter meets the mentioned conditions.

Combine these two with the [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive and you'll have your problem solved:

```
# Note that the map block must be placed outside
# the server block
map $request_uri $skipcache {
    # Enable caching in general
    default 0;

    # But disable it for these URLs
    "/a" 1;
    "/b" 1;
    # You can also use regular expressions here
    "~^/c/d$" 1;
}

server {
    ...

    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...

        # cache
        fastcgi_cache projectdomain.com;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skipcache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skipcache;

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```